# Magento CSP issue: Refused to load the script

Tags: magento2, csp

I whitelisted all domains in my module's csp_whitelist.xml  file and it is working as expected except google-analytics, I tried adding it to the file but after adding it is giving the same error.

I tried disabling the magento_Csp module, even after that google-analytics CSP issue is always in the console.

Is there any other way to fix it?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<csp_whitelist xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Csp:etc/csp_whitelist.xsd">
    <policies>
        <policy id="script-src">
            <values>
                <value id="google-analytics" type="host">*.google-analytics.com</value>
            </values>
        </policy>
    </policies>
</csp_whitelist>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<csp_whitelist xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Csp:etc/csp_whitelist.xsd">
    <policies>
        <policy id="script-src">
            <values>
                <value id="google-analytics" type="host"">*.google-analytics.com</value>
                <value id="data" type="host">'self' data:</value>
            </values>
        </policy>
        <policy id="img-src">
            <values>
                <value id="google-analytics" type="host">*.google-analytics.com</value>
                <value id="data" type="host">'self' data:</value>
            </values>
        </policy>
    </policies>
</csp_whitelist>
```